# How to provide const read-only access to a wrapper class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following program. What I would like to accomplish is to create a constant reference to a mutable wrapper over unordered_map that I can pass around for read-only lookup. However, I am not able to compile the following code, due to the operator[] overloads.

From this code, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using std::unordered_map;
using std::string;

class M {
private:
    unordered_map<string, string> m;

public:
    string const& operator[](string const& s) const {
        return m[s]; // line 13
    }

    string& operator[](string const& s) {
        return m[s];
    }
};

int main() {
    M m;

    m[string("a")] = string("answer_a");

    M const& m1 = m;
    string const& test = m1[string("a")];

    return 0;
}
```

The error (on line 13) is

> error: passing 'const std::unordered_map,
>   std::basic_string >' as 'this' argument of
>   'std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true,
>   _Hashtable>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::operator[](const _Key&)
>   [with _Key = std::basic_string, _Pair = std::pair, std::basic_string >, _Hashtable =
>   std::_Hashtable, std::pair, std::basic_string >,
>   std::allocator,
>   std::basic_string > >, std::_Select1st, std::basic_string > >,
>   std::equal_to >,
>   std::hash >,
>   std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
>   std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash,
>   std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>,
>   std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true,
>   _Hashtable>::mapped_type = std::basic_string]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: What you're doing wrong is failing to read the documentation to find out what `operator[]` does for maps.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote the question though, it is a fair question and I'm pretty sure all of us made such mistakes before. Especially when http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/3093378 is the 3-rd most voted question on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unordered_map operator[] is non-const, because it adds a map key when it does not exist yet. Instead, you should use

```
return m.at(s);
```